# How to define start order

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using Helm3. I have an Main-Application that uses a Database. I also have a SpringBoot Setup-Application that uses Liquibase to setup the Database and do some more Init-Stuff. As this Setup-Application is not allowed to run parallel, i defined it in a "pre-install,pre-upgrade" Helm-Hock.

Now for Develop environment it would be handy if the Database would start with the Helm Chart too. The Order would look like this.

1. start DB
2. run setup app
3. start the rest defined in the Helm Chart?

Do you know how to implement this with Helm3 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use helm hook `helm.sh/hook-weight` in order to define the order.
As it is explained in [Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/):

> It is possible to define a weight for a hook which will help build a deterministic executing order. Weights are defined using the following annotation:

```
annotations:
  "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
```

> Hook weights can be positive or negative numbers but must be represented as strings. When Helm starts the execution cycle of hooks of a particular Kind it will sort those hooks in ascending order.

If you need to have your db up and running, you can install the helm chart with the the flag `--wait`. With this flag enabled, it will wait until all resources are in a ready state and will not run the `post-install` hook until they are ready.

Comment: the DB Image should not be created in the hook. there images created in the hook are not managed but the DB need to be managed. [see](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#hook-resources-are-not-managed-with-corresponding-releases). it should be shut down it the release is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying start-up order is actually an anti-pattern in kubernetes. The idea is to make service resilient to dependency/service failures.

I would let the application fail till the db comes up or use init containers.

More info about [Kubernetes Anti-Patterns](https://medium.com/better-programming/10-antipatterns-for-kubernetes-deployments-e97ce1199f2d)